# Spring security class working In different port try to login with valid credentials from apk ,got "**anonymousUser**"

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security

I have server side code working in 8080 port which has spring security implemented, I am trying to hit that from 8100 .apk (Ionic Browser view). Inside my Login controller I got the `anonymousUser` in success Part.

My server side loggedInSuccess method code is,

`Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

I got the below thing in Authentication reference (`auth`) 
`org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS`

Then the I added `getPrinciple()`

`Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

In `principal` ref I got only one string `anonymousUser`.

If the same code working perfectly in desktop version like `Spring boot project`.The problem came only in ionic to server side code accessing time.The username and pwd is correct but I got it as `anonymousUser`.Below I posted my java sec config code.

**Security Java config**

```
  @Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/user/createsocialuser");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler loginFailureHandler = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();

        loginFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login/loginFailure");

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .regexMatchers("/admin.*").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .regexMatchers("/user.*").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .usernameParameter("j_username") 
            .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login/loginSuccess")
            .permitAll()
            .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied/403");
    }


}
```

**CORS Filter code** for accessing different ports 
Inside my **main()**

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(simpleCORSFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setName("simpleCORSFilter");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    } 

    @Bean(name = "simpleCORSFilter")
    public Filter simpleCORSFilter() {
        return new SimpleCORSFilter();
    }
```

**SimpleCORSFilter class**

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter  implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Finally **Login Controller**

```
 @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class LoginController {
                @RequestMapping(value="/loginSuccess",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public  ResponseWrapper  create(Principal principle) {  

            try {
                        ResponseWrapper wrap = new ResponseWrapper();
                Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
                wrap.setResult(principal);
                wrap.setResponseSuccess("success");
                System.out.println("-------sucess********----------------");
                return wrap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value="/loginFailure",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public  ResponseWrapper  loginFailure( ) {  

            try {
                ResponseWrapper wrap = new ResponseWrapper();
                wrap.setResponseError("loginFailed");
                        return wrap;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

In angular ui i got this as a response from server side while i hit it from apk(Ionic browser window)

```
$scope.doLogin = function(loginform,userDetails) {
            if (loginform.$valid) {
                           $http.post(RestURL.baseURL+'/j_spring_security_check?j_username='+self.login.email+'&j_password='+self.login.password)
             .success(function(data){ 
                             if(data.responseError == "loginFailed"){                    
                     $location.url('login');
                 }              
           if(data.responseSuccess == "success"){
              if(data.result != null){
                  var serverData = data.result;
                  console.warn('Server data =>',angular.toJson(serverData));
// I got it like Server data => {"responseError":null,"responseDenied":null,"responseSuccess":"success","result":"anonymousUser"}
                  $rootScope.userData= serverData;
                  $location.url('/home');
              }
           }
           }).error(function(data){          
            //callback 
            console.log('Error Some Internal server Error',data);
           });
             } else {
              $log.log("form is invalid!");
              if (self.isNewUser) {
               loginform["username"].$dirty = true;
               loginform["usrtel"].$dirty = true;
              } 
              loginform["email"].$dirty = true;
              loginform["password"].$dirty = true;
             }
            };
```

**Login html code**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 form">
      <h1 class="title lead">Sign In</h1>
      <form class="form-horizontal" name="loginform" data-ng-submit="doLogin(loginform,userDetails)">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.login.email" id="j_username" placeholder="Enter username" name="j_username" >
          <label for="password">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="$parent.login.password" id="j_password" placeholder="Enter password" type="password" name="j_password">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" id="loginerror" role="alert">
            invalid usermame or password
          </div><br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

From ionic browser window I got two request (`GET` and `POST`)called to server side `login spring security code` below I pasted my Images

For `Get` request images

[image: Get request From Ionic to Java]

[image: Get request remaining data]

For `Post` request images

[image: PoST request for same login URL]

[image: POST request remainig data]

Both `GET` and `POST` request called automatically only in ionic app,but the same I ran it only in spring boot called `Post` only called to the login security url . Is this create `anonymousUser` problem in my ionic app .

Comment: Are you sending the csrf token?

Comment: csrf token is disabled. please have a look at it.

Comment: i think that this happens because of session id.

Comment: try this filters="none" in your url.

Comment: @jlumietu nope, I pasted above my HTML code ,is that right or anything I need to add it

Comment: @jlumietu could you please tell me Am I did any mistake in html and csrf in java config class.

Comment: @jlumietu I pasted above `Authentication`  data what I got in my program. Is that okay  or I need to add anything in `security  java config` class for `/login` urls

Comment: First check if the ionic app is sending the authentication request as real post paramaters. Some frontend frameworks translate it into json. Then, i'm not sure about the `and()` before `csrf().disable()`. Try as well without this `and()`.

Comment: @jlumietu Okay I am checking ..,

Comment: if I am tried to remove the `and()` I got the error where do i paste `csrf().disable()` i tried all the lines in security config class inside `configure` method it showed me error @jlumietu

Comment: @jlumietu I saw the `Network` console in chrome it shown two request one is `GET` and `POST` for same login spring security url .

Comment: @jlumietu I removed the `and()` for `csrf().disable()` updated above security config code

Comment: Dp you have any serve side log traces to see what is happening in the security filters?

Comment: at the back end the `login success` method is executed one time and spring security `UserServiceDetails` class also executed one time but the request is made two times can i post that in image format and I have only sysout..,  @jlumietu

Comment: @jlumietu I added the images for `GET` and `POST` request called in my ionic app to server side spring security login url . Is these making any probs .. to the logging user in my app

Comment: @jlumietu is that GET request automatically called and executed before the `post`  request execute , is that make any probs

Comment: @jlumietu please give some suggestion plz I am totally dead plz

Comment: @jlumietu  for the `GET` request cause is that prblm? I am not sure how the get request called in my ionic app at the time of user login . ionic automatically added as a first then redirects to post

Comment: If the login works correctly from a view like a jsp, error might be in cors filter or in the ionic side

Comment: but the ionic Only made  `get` request in my app , i am not do any other code thats why i am confused @jlumietu

Comment: The get request ends with a 302 redirect to the login success url. What do you expect to get as response from the server after this call? Maybe a json?

Comment: actually it supposed to be a `post` request but i got first `get` @jlumietu

Comment: after the `post` request i got whole `principal` object in my login controller @jlumietu

Comment: but instead of the user details I got only string `anonymusUser` inside that @jlumietu

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the ionic browser is keeping the session cookie. I'm afraid the login is being performed correctly and sending the redirect to the `.defaultSuccessUrl("/login/loginSuccess")` but when the ionic browser redirects to this page SecurityContextHolder cannot be reached because the session is lost